# Webpack 4 won't load files after renaming to jsx extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to import jsx files without using the file extensions, like `import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';` and as long as the original file is named `LandingPage.js` this works fine, but if I rename it to `LandingPage.jsx` it doesn't work anymore. I already added `resolve.extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']` to my webpack config file and nothing changed. If I try to import a jsx file, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/LandingPage' in 'C:\Users\myself\Documents\Projects\react-app-starter\src'
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
const path = require('path');
const BrotliPlugin = require('brotli-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

require('dotenv-defaults').config({
    path: `${__dirname}/.env`,
    encoding: 'utf8',
    defaults: `${__dirname}/.env.sample`,
});

const commonConfig = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /template\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        removeComments: false,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/',
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.geojson$/,
                loader: 'json-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            defaults: `${__dirname}/.env.sample`,
            path: `${__dirname}/.env`,
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/template.html',
            title: process.env.APP_TITLE,
            filename: 'index.html',
            favicon: './src/favicon.ico',
        }),
    ],
};

if (process.env.BABEL_USE_MATERIAL_UI_ES_MODULES) {
    commonConfig.resolve = {
        alias: {
            '@material-ui/core': '@material-ui/core/es',
        },
    };
}

module.exports = (env, argv = { mode: 'development' }) => {
    switch (argv.mode) {
        default:
        case 'development': {
            return {
                ...commonConfig,
                devServer: {
                    compress: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_COMPRESS === 'true',
                    host: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST,
                    open: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_OPEN === 'true',
                    port: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_PORT,
                    historyApiFallback: true,
                },
                devtool: 'eval-source-map',
            };
        }

        case 'production': {
            return {
                ...commonConfig,
                output: {
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
                    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
                },
                optimization: {
                    splitChunks: {
                        cacheGroups: {
                            commons: {
                                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                                name: 'vendors',
                                chunks: 'all',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                plugins: [
                    ...commonConfig.plugins,
                    new BrotliPlugin({
                        asset: '[path].br[query]',
                        test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
                        threshold: 10240,
                        minRatio: 0.8,
                    }),
                ],
            };
        }
    }
};
```

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.cache(false);

    const conditionalPresets = [];

    const presets = [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-env',
        ...conditionalPresets,
    ];

    const conditionalPlugins = (process.env.BABEL_USE_MATERIAL_UI_ES_MODULES === 'true') ?
        [
            [
                'import', {
                    libraryName: '@material-ui/icons',
                    libraryDirectory: '',
                    camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
            ],
        ]
        : [
            [
                'import',
                {
                    libraryName: '@material-ui/core',
                    libraryDirectory: '',
                    camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
                '@material-ui/core',
            ],
            [
                'import',
                {
                    libraryName: '@material-ui/core/colors',
                    libraryDirectory: '',
                    camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
                '@material-ui/core/colors',
            ],
            [
                'import',
                {
                    libraryName: '@material-ui/core/styles',
                    libraryDirectory: '',
                    camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
                '@material-ui/core/styles',
            ],
            [
                'import',
                {
                    libraryName: '@material-ui/icons',
                    libraryDirectory: '',
                    camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
                '@material-ui/icons',
            ],
        ];

    const plugins = [
        '@babel/proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/transform-runtime',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
        ...conditionalPlugins,
    ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

My build script: `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --progress"`